# How can I get this text with the ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have this code in HTML :

```
<td id="t_startdate">2019-04-29 00:00</td>
```

And I would like to get `2019-04-29 00:00` using jquery I tried this :

```
var start = $('#t_startdate');
```

But when I try to show the variable start with :

```
alert(start);
```

I get `undefined`

Could you help me please ?

Thank you !

Comment: try `var start = $('#t_startdate').text()`

Comment: in this case, `.innerHTML` works too

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg i guess it won't work due tu the alert gives `undefined`. Should give `[object Object]` if jQuery had found that element

Comment: Perfect it works !

Comment: really? how could it be undefined? :D

Comment: @messerbill : I guess, that's not an actual alert message (it should've been `[object Object]`, just like you say). Probably, OP refers to `undefined` message in the console as he's assigning `start` variable. Anyways, `.text()` is what he needs.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var start = jQuery('#t_startdate').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .text() method for accessing the text of the . 
like:

```
t_startdate = $('#t_startdate').text();
alert(t_startdate);
```

[You can see this for clarification](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text)

Answer (score 0):

You can get it like below:

```
$('#t_startdate').textContent
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to wait because ur document is not ready! He said its undefined because its not loaded...

use:

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
           var start = jQuery('#t_startdate').text();
           alert(start);
       });
```